# Using npm on angular project but it displays nothing when adding angular component

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular6

I am using a angular login example found online that we use npm start to run. My problem is when i generate a component and add it to the app.modules.js file, the app doesn't display anything just a white page with a loading... on the top left. can this be because i am using npm? when i posted it on stackblitz and added the sidebar component it worked but locally if i add a componenet by ng generate component test and as soon as i add it to the app.modules.js file it shows the white screen but once removed it works perfectly fine. the stackbliz and origional github link is provided below

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydiywh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

github: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/14/nodejs-mongodb-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management

when i run ng serve --open i get the following error

error after installing module

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs//src/tsconfig.app.json'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/src/tsconfig.app.json'
    at Object.statSync (fs.js:815:3)
    at AngularCompilerPlugin._setupOptions (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:96:16)
    at new AngularCompilerPlugin (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:61:14)
    at _createAotPlugin (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:41:12)
    at Object.getNonAotConfig (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:47:19)
    at BrowserBuilder.buildWebpackConfig (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/browser/index.js:82:37)
    at DevServerBuilder.buildWebpackConfig (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js:111:46)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.check_port_1.checkPort.pipe.operators_1.concatMap [as project] (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js:38:40)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:65:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:55:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at TapSubscriber._next (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/tap.js:62:26)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocsnode_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocsnode_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:84:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:25:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/xxx/Library/Mobile/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
```

.angular.cli file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "new-cli": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "new-cli:build"
          },
          "configurations": {}
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "new-cli:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "new-cli-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application"
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "new-cli"
}
```

error in chrome inspect when adding component and running npm start

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'SidebarModule' declared by the 
 module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component 
 annotation. at syntaxError 
 (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:1270) 
 at eval 
 (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10888) 
 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at 
 CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata 
 (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10870) 
 at JitCompiler._loadModules 
 (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24112) 
 at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents 
 (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24093) 
 at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync 
 (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24053) 
 at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync 
 (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser- 
 dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js?:158) at 
 PlatformRef.bootstrapModule 
 (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:4649) at eval 
 (webpack:///./src/main.ts?:6)
```

Comment: 1)which cli version are you using globally in your system?
2)have you installed angular cdk ?

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal i added the angular cdk and i am using angular 6 cli

Comment: posted a solution for your error @z123

Comment: this error means its not able to find `tsconfig.app.json` whose path is in `.angular.cli.json ` kindly check whether the path mentioned there is correct @z123

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal i have a .angular.json file and it has it correct. I posted it up

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal i fixed the ts config file but when i run ng serve, i still see a white loading screen if i add a angular compoonent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here are the steps to reproduce for your 'local' stackblitz to work:

1 - generate your project with `ng new myApp`
2 - download the stackblitz project via the export button, then extract the files inside of the compressed folder.
3 - in the extracted folder, go to the `src` folder, then inside of it click on the second `src` folder.
4 - copy the `app` and the `main.ts` file and paste them to the first `src` folder.
5 - open the `typings.d` file in the second `src` folder and copy the line inside. and paste this line in the `typings.d` file in the first `src` folder.
6 - delete the second `src` folder.
7 - replace the `src` folder in your project root with the one from the extracted folder.
8 - run this command in your project root: `npm install --save ng-sidebar`
9 - run `npm start`

You can now create how many components you want this will still works.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Angular CLI:

```
npm install @angular/cli
```

Then run this from the app directory. It should open a browser to localhost:4200

```
ng serve --open
```

Comment: tried that i get the following error i will post in the origional description

Comment: When it says 'cannot find module' just npm install "whatever module". In the error case it'd be `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular`

EDITED: You might want to use the -g flag as well.

Comment: @Collin Knapp that solved the module error but now i get a different error i will post above

Comment: OK. I'm going to submit another answer.

Comment: i will post an error i found that shows on chrome inspect when i run the project using npm start

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

this should solve your dev kit error its a new dependancy introduced in angular 6 and has to be saved as dev dependancy

Comment: this 2nd error you are getting means its not able to find tsconfig.app.json whose path is in .angular.cli.json kindly check whether the path mentioned there is correct @z123

Comment: also can you try creating a new application with `ng new` command and try doing an ng-serve of that app whether that works

Comment: when i created a new peoject with the ng new and hit ng serve i got This command can only be run inside of a CLI project.

Answer (score 0):

So I went to the site you cited and downloaded the github project.

I followed the instructions on the page and was able to run it with no issue.

I tried to add a component via "ng" and was unable to. I kept getting a variety of errors related to angular.json not being able to be located and so on. I'm not sure what you did to get the component in there, but it seems like that is related to the problem. The cli cannot run this project out of the box it seems to require the use of npm.

After looking through some of the source it seems that this is Angular on Webpack, so the CLI won't work for you. It won't allow you to create components either.

Comment: so how do i create componenets then

Comment: Manually. Essentially copy one of the components like login/register, rename it, then add it to app component and wherever you are using it.

Comment: i found a better way, as observablerxvs mentioned i just uploaded the whole project to stackblitx and exported it from there created a new angular project and replaced the files not it works.